# TypeScript error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type for Typography

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to use Typography component from material-ui with TypeScript, but I am getting this weird error

```
TypeScript error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, any> | FunctionComponent<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>> | undefined'.  TS2322

     8 | }
     9 | export default ({ text, date }: Props) => (
  > 10 |   <Typography component="p" gutterBottom>
       |               ^
    11 |     {text && <span>{text}:&nbsp;</span>}
    12 |     <FormattedDate value={date} />
    13 |     &nbsp;
```

Here's how my component looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormattedDate, FormattedTime } from 'react-intl';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

interface Props {
  date: Date;
  text?: string;
}
export default ({ text, date }: Props) => (
  <Typography component="p" gutterBottom>
    {text && <span>{text}:&nbsp;</span>}
    <FormattedDate value={date} />
    &nbsp;
    <FormattedTime value={date} />
  </Typography>
);
```

I am not able to understand why `"p"` is not an acceptable value for `component` prop. I tried it with `"h1"` and "`h2"` which fails in the same way and apparently, the [official demo](https://material-ui.com/components/typography/) also uses the string.

Is there anything I am missing?, I don't want to ignore this with `// @ts-ignore`, but want to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Had this in 2021, the problem was that I was spreading `HTMLAttributes` of an input against `InputBase`, while I should have properly spreaded `InputBaseProps` instead.

In my case it was related to an input, but same can be replicated for every component: as long as you use a material UI component, you should provide the properties it asks and properly set the correct props types if you use/extend them.

**Example that gives error:**

```
import { HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';

import inputStyle from 'Input.module.scss';

export interface InputProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  
}

export function Input(props: InputProps) {
  const { ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <InputBase
      fullWidth={true}
      className={[inputStyle.input].join(' ')}
      color='primary'
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}
```

(in this ccase, an error was raised on `color`)

**Proper way to do this:**

```
import InputBase, { InputBaseProps } from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';

import inputStyle from 'Input.module.scss';

export interface InputProps extends InputBaseProps {
  
}

export function Input(props: InputProps) {
  const { ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <InputBase
      fullWidth={true}
      className={[inputStyle.input].join(' ')}
      color='primary'
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per reference document provided by Material UI for Typography
(https://material-ui.com/api/typography/)

```
{ h1: 'h1', h2: 'h2', h3: 'h3', h4: 'h4', h5: 'h5', h6: 'h6', subtitle1: 'h6', subtitle2: 'h6', body1: 'p', body2: 'p',}
```

`variantMapping` has these mapping so going forward if you want to use `<p>` tags you can use variant type as body1 or body2 instead of component prop.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow! There's no mention in the docs where they said support for component prop is going away. I do want to use component prop as it works, but TypeScript is behaving weird.

Comment: The description for the "component" clearly mentions The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a DOM element or a component. By default, it maps the variant to a good default headline component.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't mean that it should throw errors for strings. We're not discussing here about whether to use component prop or not. I am asking how to fix the TypeScript error. I am asking this because I am using the `component` prop at multiple places in my project and I can't change all of them and manually test everywhere.

Comment: Same for me. I can use the code sandbox on the official site to change the root element to div or p (or whatever) using a string in the component prop, but typescript has suddenly started to show errors. @ArpitBhatia is the component prop going to be dropped? Is there some information about this that you can link us to? Is there am official reason why we should not use component prop that you have found?

Answer (score 0):

I have this since I updated to `material-ui/core@4.6.0` and `typescript@3.7.2`.

I managed to silence the errors by using `component={'div' as any}` so I'm posting this as a temporary answer, but I do think there must be a better fix coming up.